# Remove port number in wsdl

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

I need to remove the port number in the wsdl file of my WCF service.

I use the IWsdlExportExtension and IEndpointBehavior in order to do that but it always ended up with the original port number.

Note: if I modify the all uri and not just remove the port number, the wsdl is modified with the new uri.

Anybody know if it's a bug or a feature of the .net framework?

And if it's another way to do that?
I heard about a KB correcting this issue but I can't find it.

Edit:
I've found the [KB](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB971842) but I don't want to use it because it's not fully tested.

Comment: How is a Service going to work without a port?

Comment: It will use the default port: for http it's 80. In this case I don't need a port because the service will be hosted in several servers behind a load-balancer. The access to the load-balancer doesn't use a port, but the access to the servers use a particulary port. If the WSDL service location contains a port, the client can't reach the service if it's generated from the WSDL.